# How to automate web scraping using php?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, cron, web-scraping

Let me explain my situation.

I have a list of 10 million page urls. I want those pages scraped and saved in the database as raw html.

As of now I'm using CURL to scrap those pages. Every time I access `index.php`, it scraps one page url and save it in the database.

Now I think its not possible to access that `index.php` 10 million times by myself using browser.

I could use `do while loop`. But I think its gonna take hell of a time to complete the task.  And memory issues too.

So can someone point me in the right direction to make this task painless.

I own a Linux VPS server with `1GB RAM` and WHM/cPanel.

PS: I considered CRON. But i have to define the time in cron. Even if I run the script every 1 minute using cron, I can only complete `1440 urls in 24 hours`.  So can some one give me some idea to complete `atleast 100,000` urls in one day using cron?.

Comment: command line, there shouldn't be a browser any where near this. good luck (sounds like you need it)

Comment: @Dagon Thanks for your comment. It would be cool if you can explain little bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is some high-speed fetching library like `wget` or `curl` to do the heavy lifting for you. PHP could create lists of work for these programs to process, and `wget` in particular has an option for fetching and saving the contents of URLs from a list given in a file.

A PHP script run from a browser must finish in a reasonable amount of time or it will time out. It is not normally used for background processes like this.

You can use `crontab` to check for new work and launch a new `wget` process. There is no reason you only have to fetch one URL at a time. You could do as many are in the listed files.

For example, a cron job could kick off a script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

for list in "/tmp/*.urls"
do
  wget -i $list -b
end
```

Of course, there are a lot of options for `wget` that can be tweaked.

If you're certain that your PHP app is secured, you could even write out shell scripts to be run by `cron` in the background at a later time. This way you can specify the exact destination of each file.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your detailed answer. Looks like shell scripting is the way to go. But I'm kind of new to shell scripting. Can I still save the raw html data in the mysql database using shell scripting?

Comment: Putting millions of HTML pages in a database is going to be nothing but trouble, honestly. MySQL is not an especially good document store. You can use `bash` to interface with the `mysqlimport` command-line tool and import tab-delimited data, for instance, but it might be better to use a more robust scripting language like Ruby or Python for this part.

Answer (score 3):

I hope you have a good broadband plan! =)

The simple answer using `cron` is to run a shell script that scrapes at least 70 URLs.  That meets your target of at least 100,000 per day (if the cron fires every minute).

The `wget` command is probably what you want, for retrieving pages.

I would also suggest that you have another process that resolves IP addresses on a less-frequent timescale.  You don't really want to do a name lookup every time you access a page.  `wget` will be much happier if you give it an IP address.

[edit] Just a thought, however.  It's unlikely that you can scrape each page in less than one second if you do it sequentially.  So you might want to fork a new process for each URL.  This could be as simple as using the `&` on the `wget` incantation to background the job.  To offer some kind of sanity, maybe spawn a batch of 10 at a time and then sleep for 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its very helpful. What is the minimum required broadband plan to meet 100,000 url cap.? Will 2MBPS plan enough? If not can I use my vps server to scrap the pages?

Comment: Well, let's just suppose that the average page returns 20kB of data.  You scrape 100k of these every day, which amounts to about 60 GB of monthly traffic.